# Youtube page loading in UIWebView and not the video

Tags: html, uiwebview, io, youtube, embed

```
    NSString *youTubeHTMLTemplate = @"<html><body style=\"margin:0;padding:0;\"><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
    finalHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeHTMLTemplate, htmlFrameWidth, htmlFrameHeight, videoID];
[videoWebView loadHTMLString:finalHtml baseURL:nil];
```

The above code is properly loading video (ONLY) but if I provide small height and width (<100) the UIWebView is loaded with the whole page (Video + comments and all). I can scroll and check the whole page. I am expecting to load video only.

Any idea what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this. Writing an answer if anyone find it useful.
This is from YouTube's JS API documentation
"To allow room for critical player functionality, players must be at least 200px by 200px."